# centering a css menu

Tags: css, menu, center

I am having some trouble getting this menu centered.
I tried `text-align:center;` on the `<ul>` and `margin:auto;`.
I'm not sure if I have to float anything, or change the display setting

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FQ3mK/

Comment: Sorry I don't use stack overflow very often

Comment: Please read the FAQs if you're unsure how the site works.

Answer (score 2):

**First method:** center the container `<div>` by using `text-align:center`:

```css
#navcontainer {
    text-align: center;   
}
```

**Live demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FQ3mK/1/)**

---

**Second method:** give a fixed width to the container `<div>` and use `margin:auto`:

```css
#navcontainer {
    width: 600px;
    margin: auto;   
}
```

**Live demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FQ3mK/2/)**

Comment: I didn't know a fixed width was required for margin:auto to work thank you

Answer (score 1):

margin:auto works only if you give the container (the `<ul`) a fixed width.

see: http://jsfiddle.net/FQ3mK/3/

Answer (score 0):

I too was looking into this. I found the best answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17634702/2537445

I think it's the best because it is the most dynamic, cross-browser compatible answer.

As to your particular anchors, you wouldn't be able to use display: block on them.

However, you can apply padding to the left and right of an inline anchor, and padding to the top and bottom of an inline li to give the spacing you need.

```
#cssmenu ul {
   text-align:center;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
   display: inline;
}
```