# How to create a drop down menu with auto-width and centered below previous element?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a drop-down menu in which sub-elements are centered below the content above them, and which automatically adjusts box size based on the width of the largest list item.  I have a workable solution now, but it is entirely based on absolute values, which is something I would like to avoid.

http://jsfiddle.net/braLf708/

I'm sure it's pretty messy coding regardless, because this is the first project I am assigning myself to learn how to build a website.

All help is appreciated.

```
Obligatory code to allow link to jFiddle
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Answer (score 1):

This similar question has been asked on SO. 
[How To Center A CSS Drop Down Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17634627/how-to-center-a-css-drop-down-menu)

They have JSFiddle examples there that seem to work pretty well. 
One of the last commentators posted a jsfiddle that worked well without explicit offset margins.

Good luck!

Comment: I think I asked the question poorly.  The top level menu is already centered.  I am trying to center the submenus below the elements they come down from though.  I'll update to add a jfiddle to my question.

Comment: Did you run the fiddler I was mentioning? the drop down menus were centered too. Cool post a fiddler if you could and Ill take a look. User pzin's fiddler post has the code. http://jsfiddle.net/y4vDC/13/